# How to Auto convert 1 place decimal value of Edittext | Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, decimalformat

I need to show edittext value with 1 decimal value.

```
Example - 
User enter = 1000 then output must be look like 1.000
```

Please help me out.

Comment: do you want to convert it in scientific notation?

Comment: I need to convert value into decimal format.
Example - 
User enter = 1000 then output must be look like 1.000

Comment: You already mention that in question. What will be your expected output if user enters "123456" ?

Answer (score 2):

**Try This:**

```
   String val="1000";

   String newval=val.substring(0,1)+"."+val.substring(1);

   Toast.makeText(this, "Decimal Amount"+newval,   
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: @Shoeb Siddique... Do work on this Answer on textwatcher on Edittext